# Difference between convergence and idempotence in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, theory, configuration-management

What is the basic difference between convergence and idempotence in Chef?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Convergence and idempotence are not Chef-specific. They're generally attributed to configuration management theory, though have use in other fields, notably mathematics.

Let's start with the more basic, idempotent. We're going to ignore the mathematic use of idempotent, and focus instead on what configuration management people mean when they talk about it. That is: "multiple applications of the same action do not have side effects on the system state." A simple example of an idempotent operation is `mkdir -p`:

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/statedir/myapp
```

No matter how many times we run this command, it will result in that tree being created. Another way of stating this about idempotent operations is, "running the tool over and over doesn't change the system after the first time."

Now to contrast that with convergence. Generically, to converge means to bring [people or] things together. In configuration management, convergence means to bring the system state in line with a defined policy. That is, changes are made on the system only if they need to be made. A simple example of a convergent operation is:

```
if [ ! -d /var/lib/statedir/myapp ]; then
  mkdir -p /var/lib/statedir/myapp
fi
```

This is convergent because we're only executing the mkdir command if the desired directory does not exist. We also call this a "test and repair" operation. That is, we test the current state of the specific thing we're managing, and then repair it with a specific command or operation if it is not in that state. That is what Chef does behind the scenes with a resource like this:

```
directory '/var/lib/statedir/myapp' do
  recursive true
end
```

The way we (Chef) talk about this is that Chef takes idempotent actions to converge the system to the state declared by the various resources. Every resource in Chef is declarative, and performs a test about the current state of the resource, and then repairs the system to match that.

To get deeper into the weeds about how Chef works, it has a "compile" phase and a "converge" phase in a Chef run. In the "compile" phase, it evaluates the Ruby recipes on the node, and it is looking for resource objects that it adds to a "resource collection." Once it has evaluated all the recipes, it then enters the "converge" phase where it iterates over the resource collection, taking the appropriate action to put the resources into the desired state, whereby users are created, files are written, packages are installed, and so forth.

Comment: That was a really great explanation!! I was aware of convergence concept in chef but not idempotence. Thanks for articulation. :)

Comment: -1. I don't find this to be a particularly clear explanation; it makes idempotence and convergence sound like they are basically the same thing, since you the commands you use as examples of the two concepts are semantically identical. An example of an idempotent-but-not-convergent command (or a convergent-but-not-idempotent command, if such a thing even makes sense) would add clarity.

Answer (score 8):

#### Definitions

To say that an operation is *convergent* roughly means that it puts whatever part of the system it manages into a specified state.

When configuration management people say that an operation is *idempotent*, they typically mean that if you run it a second time right after running it once, the second run will terminate immediately without doing any redundant work.

When a resource is described as idempotent in the context of *Chef* in particular, it means that subsequent Chef runs after the resource has already been put into the desired state don't count it as "updated" in the *x/y resources updated* message at the end of the run.

Note that most built-in resources satisfy this final, strictest definition of idempotence by default, and you can achieve it in your own recipes and custom resources by using [`only_if` and `not_if`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#guards) guards and [`converge_if_changed`](https://docs.chef.io/dsl_custom_resource.html#converge-if-changed).

#### Some commentary, and a note about other definitions

Confusingly, the majority of definitions of "idempotent" you find on the internet will *not* match either of the ones I've just given. Rather than trusting what the experts *say* the definition is, I'm inferring it from observing how they *actually use* the term. It is infuriatingly common to find somebody give a definition of "idempotent" and then use the word in a way that clearly doesn't cohere with that definition a few paragraphs later.

To explore this, let's start by exploring definitions of "idempotent" that exist outside of the field of configuration management. Lots of such definitions are listed on Wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence. The ones that most frequently get (wrongly) given as the meaning of idempotence in a configuration management context are as follows:

- In mathematics, a function *f* is said to be idempotent if *f(f(x)) = f(x)* for all possible values of *x*.
- In mathematics, a whole slew of other sorts of mathematical objects are said to be idempotent if they meet some formal definition or other (generally with a common theme of "doing an operation repeatedly has the same effect as doing it once").
- In programming, to say that a function or procedure is idempotent means one of two things:

  1. In the case of a function that takes an argument and returns a value, exactly the same as the mathematical meaning.
  2. In the case of a function that has side effects, that, after calling the function once, subsequent calls leave the system state unchanged.

A slew of confused sources give one of these definitions as the meaning of "idempotent" in a configuration management context, and then promptly go on to use the term in a way that makes clear that it's not really the definition they're using. Some examples:

- Pace's [competing answer to this very question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49459948/1709587). There he claims that:

  > A step is idempotent if, after multiple executions of the step on a system (whose underlying state has not changed), the result is the same as if the step had been executed once.

  but then goes on to give this as an example of a step that isn't idempotent:

  ```
    rm -rf /var/log/myapp
    mkdir -p /var/log/myapp
  ```

  Clearly this step does in fact meet Pace's definition of idempotence, since running it multiple times in a row gets us to the same final state as running it once (namely, a state where `/var/log/myapp` exists and is empty). However, it does redundant work when run a second time, and so Pace describes it as non-idempotent.
- Mischa Taylor and Seth Vargo's book *Learning Chef: A Guide to Configuration Management and Automation*. In there, they claim:

  > When Chef code is *idempotent*, it can run multiple times on the same system and the results will always be identical, without producing unintended side effects.

  but then later, commenting on one of their example recipes:

  > Does our recipe pass the idempotency test? Sadly, no. ... Chef mistakenly thinks there’s still stuff it needs to do—2/3 resources updated in this second run. If the recipe were truly idempotent, we’d see 0/3 resources updated. Chef would inspect the state of the system, recognize that nothing had changed since the last run—no one touched the node between the two runs—and perform no resource updates

  Again, they're stating a definition of idempotence based upon the system state being unchanged when a recipe is run multiple times, but actually *using* the word to mean that unnecessary work is avoided.
- Ben Ford's [*Idempotence: not just a big and scary word*](https://puppet.com/blog/idempotence-not-just-a-big-and-scary-word) on the Puppet blog, where he first gives this definition of idempotence...

  > Idempotence is simply a word that describes an operation that will have the same effect whether you run it once or 10,001 times. Adding one is not idempotent because the result keeps incrementing, but multiplying by one is idempotent because the answer is the same no matter how many times you multiply it!

  Then he gives this *example* of idempotence, which, while it *is* consistent with the definition given above, is a little suspicious - because it focuses on subsequent executions *not doing redundant work*, rather than on them *reaching the same result*:

  > Imagine a time when you were 12 and your mom asked you to take out the trash. Being the good kid you were, you dropped the GameBoy and jumped right up to do as you were asked, yeah?
  >
  > But then 30 minutes later when she walked back through the living room and saw you curled up on the couch playing "Super Mario Land," she told you again to take out the trash. I strongly suspect that you did not leap up to go take out an empty trash bag. Instead you said, "Already did it, Mom!" That's idempotence. The effect of being told once to take the trash out is the same as the effect of being told twice. You didn't do it again, because it had already been done.

  Then finally he throws his definition to the wind and gives an example of an operation that he claims is not idempotent despite the fact that repeated executions of it *will* reach the same result:

  > So how about that time you were chastised for writing non-idempotent execs? People new to Puppet generally have shell scripts they're replacing, and they write code that looks sort of like this:
  >
  > ```
  > exec { '/usr/bin/curl http: //server.net/packages/package.tar.gz -o /tmp/package.tar.gz ': }
  >
  > -> exec { 'tar -xf /tmp/package.tar.gz -C /tmp/package': }
  >
  > -> exec { '/tmp/package/installer.sh': }
  >
  > file { '/tmp/package':
  >     ensure  => absent,
  >     force   => true,
  >     require => Exec[ '/tmp/package/installer.sh'],
  > }
  >
  > file { '/tmp/package.tar.gz':
  >     ensure  => absent,
  >     force   => true,
  >     require => Exec[ '/tmp/package/installer.sh'],
  > }
  > ```
  >
  > So what's wrong with that? It works, right? Download the tarball, extract it, install the thing, then clean up after yourself. It looks like it should run perfectly, assuming no typos or network issues. And it will. But it will run perfectly every time Puppet runs. In other words, it will download and run the installer script every thirty minutes!

  But the result will be the same, Ben! Earlier, that's the detail that you told us the definition of idempotence revolved around!

  Clearly, Ben is *really* applying the "avoid redundant work" definition of idempotence, despite what he claims.

#### Can an operation be idempotent but not convergent?

Yes. Such an operation would be one that doesn't bring the system to a specified end state, but *does* avoid redundant work on consecutive runs. [Pace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49459948/1709587) gives an example of such an operation, and [Thinking Like A Chef](https://coderanger.net/thinking/) provides another:

> A system can be idempotent without being convergent. For example if we had the pseudo code `if file X does not exist, write the current timestamp to file X` that would be idempotent, but it can’t really be said to converge on a particular end state.

The best practical example I can think of of an operation that you could characterise as idempotent-but-not-convergent would be installing a package using a typical package manager's `install` command that:

- installs the latest version if the package is not installed, but
- doesn't update an older version if it's already installed.

The state (the version of the package you get) is not determined by the recipe, so it's arguably not convergent, but it successfully avoids unnecessary work.

#### Can an operation be convergent but not idempotent?

Yes, absolutely! A simple example is Ben Ford's one, already quoted above, of unconditionally downloading a file to some local path. It's convergent, because the end state is always the same (the file exists), but is not idempotent, because it does the unnecessary work of redownloading the file each time it runs.

---

For what it's worth, I find it frustrating that the configuration management community have appropriated a term that already had a clear meaning in the broader world of programming and then used it in a related but still *clearly different* way, without ever providing a formal definition of what it means in their world. A search of the Chef docs (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdocs.chef.io+idempotent) yields many uses of the term, but no definition. It's not surprising that this topic confuses people when most of the definitions of the term floating around don't match the usage.

I've only managed to find one person who has ever given definitions of idempotence that are consistent with the way the term is used, and that's coderanger (aka Noah Kantrowitz). In [Thinking Like A Chef](https://coderanger.net/thinking/), which I quoted from previously, he writes:

> “idempotently” ... means that the actor does as little as possible to achieve the desired state.

and in [an IRC conversation from 2015](https://botbot.me/freenode/chef/2015-09-01/?msg=48690138&page=7) he writes:

> Idempotent means not taking actions when they aren't needed, convergent means it "settles" on a specific final state.

Other than this one man, I have literally not been able to find anyone else who has ever given a definition of the term that matches how the whole configuration management community seems to use it.

Comment: Love how you think! We require database upgrade scripts to be idempotent (i.e. re-runnable, allow divergence); convergence (i.e. re/calculate desired state) is not required. idempotent="Has the 4.2 price markup script been run on this database?" convergent="Do the prices reflect the new markup that introduced in release 4.2?" The two are independent but can be combined to get to a desired state. combined=Don't run the price script more than once if the goal is to *initialize* the data to "4.2" state. convergent=>Run many times if the goal is to enforce pricing policy no matter what version.

Comment: What a great answer! Precisely dissects how the word "idempotent" is used to mean something a little different in practice in configuration management, despite people saying the same words to define "idempotent". This answer also made it immediately clear to me why they need the word "convergent" - because once "idempotent" ends up meaning "does not report changes / does not redo work", that makes "idempotent" useless for saying "results in the same end state", and suddenly you have to find another word that means the same thing.

Comment: My first taste of this was when someone told me my Ansible playbook was not idempotent, and I thought "what!? it messes up the desired state upon reruns!? well that's a serious bug that I need to fix!" - turned out they just meant that some of the steps reported "changed" instead of "unchanged". (To be fair, still a bug, just a superficial one - reporting changes when the resulting state is unchanged is misleading, and users have to be able to trust that the reported result does not indicate changed state unless state actually changed in a way that matters.)

Answer (score 4):

@Mark Amery asked for a more satisfying example of the difference between the two so I will endeavor to provide that.

A step is **convergent** if, at the successful conclusion of the step, the system has been brought into a known state.

A step is **idempotent** if, after multiple executions of the step on a system (whose underlying state has not changed), the result is the same as if the step had been executed once.

**Convergence without idempotence**

A step that is convergent but not idempotent is:

```
rm -rf /var/log/myapp
mkdir -p /var/log/myapp
```

At the successful conclusion of the step we know for a fact that `/var/log/myapp` is an empty directory that exists.

It is not idempotent because it blows away the `/var/log/myapp` directory each time.  Idempotence is desirable because it reduces unnecessary churn on the system.  Obviously any applications writing to the `/var/log/myapp` directory would not be happy with the above step.

**Idempotence without convergence**

A step that is idempotent but not convergent is:

```
test "$(ls -A /home/foo 2>/dev/null)" || tempfile -d /home/foo
```

That script will create a file with a random name in `/home/foo` only if there are no files in `/home/foo`.  This is idempotent, after the first run the directory will not be empty so future runs will do nothing.

However, it is not convergent.  You could not say this step is putting the system into any kind of known state because the file that gets created will have a random name.

Convergence is desired because it helps to produce systems that are in identical states and thus be more likely to behave predictably.

**A word of caution**

These terms are like abstractions, they are not exact and they can leak.  For example, you could state that an operation isn't idempotent because it uses up CPU cycles.  You could state that one idempotent test-and-repair operation that does an expensive test is "less idempotent" than another operation that does a cheap test even though "less idempotent" is not a factual thing.

You could try and state that a step that installs MySQL version X is not convergent because, when run on different machines, it leaves a different timestamp on the files.  Alternatively you could say the step I posted above IS convergent because it leaves the system in the state "/home/foo exists and contains exactly one file".

This is what happens when math escapes the chalkboard.

Comment: But, but... your definition of idempotence doesn't include "avoid unnecessary work" (which your example of Convergence without Idempotence asserts as an important aspect of idempotence). I think convergence is about applying idempotence across multiple facets of a specification until no further changes need be made. It's like trying to compare one rotation of a wheel (idempotence) with a journey by car (convergence). And your phrase "thus behave more reliably" might be better stated as "thus be more likely to behave more predictably". Good try :-)

Comment: I'm afraid I'll have to disagree.  Eliminating extra work is often a benefit of idempotent but I don't believe it is an essential requirement.  My example talked about reducing unnecessary churn and by that I meant reducing unnecessary changes because these could risk conflict or error.

I also disagree that idempotence is needed to define convergence.  I think the two are often complementary but I feel my definition is more accurate.

I agree with you on the phrasing.  I will clean that up.  You are welcome to submit your own answer regarding the other two points.

Comment: I'm with @barny; your supposed example of "Convergence without idempotence" in fact perfectly satisfies your own definition of idempotence, making that chunk of the answer self-contradictory. The example of Idemopotence without convergence makes sense and is enlightening, though!

Comment: Hmm, I guess my thought with that example was that, any time you execute that operation, you risk crashing any application using `/var/log/myapp`.  In other words, the operation has a side effect which makes it non-idempotent.

Comment: @Pace But if an application has launched and put content into `/var/log/myapp` between the two runs, that would mean that the "underlying state" of the system has changed, no? Which means, per your definition, that crashing the application is not a violation of idempotence.

Comment: By the way, I've written an answer of my own after a whole load of confused research, and criticised your "Convergence without idempotence" example in the course of it; I thought I'd flag it up so that you have the chance to comment/downvote/upvote as you see fit.