# How to not execute chef resource if directory is empty?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, cookbook

I have a resource that looks as below:

```
execute 'run_command' do
  command "chown -R user:user * "
  not_if Dir["/home/user/dir1/*"].empty?
end
```

I want to make sure that the resource is not executed if `/home/user/dir1` is empty

Comment: You won't really save all that much time; chown is pretty fast. Why does it matter?

Comment: when the directory is empty, the command doesn't work and throws an error

Comment: The error is what?

Comment: Regarding "chmod is fast", please read about [idempotency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615588/difference-between-convergence-and-idempotency-in-chef)

Comment: Does the error occur, if the directory does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
not_if { Dir.entries("/home/user/dir1/").select {|entry| ::File.join("home","user","dir1",entry) and !(entry =='.' || entry == '..') }.empty? }
```

Answer (score -2):

Just close standard error. For example:

```
execute 'chown a directory' do
  command 'chown -R user:group /path/to/directory 2>&-'
end
```

Comment: This is a pretty bad style from the point of idempotence (the reason, why @meallhour is looking for a valid guard).

Comment: @StephenKing Thanks for the bike shedding. Please look up "convergence." I won't argue it further, but you're welcome to leave your own answer for the OP.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem within the time I had. That's why I didn't leave an answer. As you seemed to be not aware of this aspect of chef, I tried to make you aware of that as friendly as possible.