# Tune Database Settings- chef

Tags: sql-server, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 using chef. Below is my chef recipe. But my task is to - Increase the buffer size(as results of common queries are returned slowly) and to - Decrease the transaction retry interval value (When transactions are failing frequently). 
Could any one insight on this and tell me how to do this

```
include_recipe 'chocolatey::default'
chocolatey 'mssqlserver2012expressadv --allow-empty-checksums' do
    action :install
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Chef template](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html) to generate a Configuration_File.ini that fits your needs and later you can use it for your installation. So assuming you have a valid configuration template under templates directory:

```
template '/foo/bar/zaz/config_file.ini' do
  source 'your.template.ini.erb'
  variables(
    variable1:node['attribute1']
    ...
    variableN:node['attributeN']
  )
  action :create
end
```

However I am afraid that the second request you have (To dynamically set parameters depending on SQL server load) is not what Chef is intended for, since it is against chef's idempotent design. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615588/difference-between-convergence-and-idempotency-in-chef).

If you are going to manage several SQL servers for different purposes, try looking at [Chef Roles](https://docs.chef.io/roles.html) and [Chef Environments](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html), so you can override the configuration template to match the needs of each solution you deploy.