# How to rerun a recipe when something is changed in data bag without logging in to chef-client machine

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a chef-client machine in which recipe accesses data bag values.
I need to rerun the chef-recipe on client machine without logging into the machine. Is their a way to rerun the recipe when their is some change to data bag.

Answer (score 1):

no, you must trigger chef-client either by logging into the machine and execute `chef-client` or by setting a periodic task (cron) which will execute `chef-client` for you.

[idempotence (and convergance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615588/difference-between-convergence-and-idempotence-in-chef) is a [main concept in chef](https://docs.chef.io/resource.html):

> Every resource has its own set of actions and properties. Most properties have default values. Some properties are available to all resources, for example those used to send notifications to other resources and guards that help ensure that some resources are idempotent.

thus, if you wrote your cookbook correctly, only the changes will be applied when you execute `chef-client`

Comment: Thanks for the info MrRoth. But in a scenario if i want to automate the process, does chef's publisher/subscriber model will work? I mean running some daemon recipe which scans for databag values if any change is their or something like that

Comment: @ArvindPurohith is that on AWS or is dedicated server?

Comment: @gskillz its a dedicated server

Answer (score 0):

To me this is a pretty custom solution. You can use SQS, SNI to AWS to achieve that. So every time when you change database you can send message with SNI and after that your node will receive notification and will run chef-client on localhost.

Comment: i am using dedicated server.